# Countability and intersection of sets.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

**If $C \subseteq [0,1]$ is uncountable, there exists an element $a \in (0,1)$ such that $C \cap [a,1]$ is uncountable.**

Indeed, namely any element $a$ such that $$a < \operatorname{sup}C.$$ In such a case, $$C \cap [a,1] = [a,\operatorname{sup}C) \quad \textrm{or} \quad C \cap [a,1] = [a,\operatorname{sup}C],$$ depending on whether $$\operatorname{sup}C \in C.$$ I have shown already that any open interval $(x_1,x_2)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable. So, $$(a, \operatorname{sup}C) \subset [a, \operatorname{sup}C) \subset [a, \operatorname{sup}C],$$ and $[a,\operatorname{sup}C)$ and $[a,\operatorname{sup}C]$ are uncountable.

**Moreover, considering the set $A$ of all elements $a \in (0,1)$ such that $C \cap [a,1]$ is uncountable, and $$\alpha := \operatorname{sup}A.$$**

Then, $C \cap [\alpha,1]$ is uncountable $iff$ $$\alpha < \operatorname{sup}C.$$ If $\alpha = \operatorname{sup}C,$ then the intersection will contain one element or no elements, depending on whether $$\operatorname{sup}C \in C.$$

Is all this true?

Comment: Let $C = [0, 0.3] \cup \{0.9\}$. Then $a < \sup C$ is not sufficient.

Comment: You are assuming $C\cap[a, 1]$ is an inteval

Comment: The line immediately following "In such a case" is wrong.

Comment: I see... alright, thanks >< I did assume C is an interval.

Comment: Rather, assume the claim is wrong. Then $C\cap[\frac1n,1]$ is countable for all $n$ ...

Comment: With regards to Lukas, the supremum of C would be 0.9,  would it not? Then, if $a < 0.9,$ it follows that $(a,0.9)$ is uncountable?

Comment: But $C \cap [a, 0.9]$ is countable for $a > 0.3$.

Comment: Ya, that's right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is wrong. A way to prove the claim is as follows:

Assume not; for each $a \in (0,1)$, $C \cap [a, 1]$ is *not* uncountable. This implies that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $A_n = C \cap \left(\dfrac{1}{n+1}, \dfrac{1}{n}\right]$ is countable. Additionally, let $A_\infty \equiv C \cap \{0\}$, which is obviously countable. But then, (including $A_\infty$ in the union)

$$C = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$$

is a countable union of countable sets, an easy injection can be made from $C \to \mathbb{N^2} \to \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: It's just a formality, but the sum is $C$, plus minus $\{0\}$. And you typed "countable" when should "uncountable", a minor mistake.

Comment: I meant to put countable for the first appearance, as I am proving the negation can't be true. Or do you mean another location?

Comment: I edited it to put "not uncountable." This is proof by contradiction, so I assume the negation of the thesis.

Comment: Ok, but i think you still should get rid of "assume not", as we don't use double negatives in english, and it looks like you are assuming the negation of what you want to disprove

Comment: It's not a double negative. I should use a semicolon instead of a comma,  however.

Comment: Why did you not define $A_n$ as $A_n := C \cap \left[\dfrac{1}{n}, 1\right]$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: can $C \cap [1/n, 1]$ be countable for every $n \in \{1, 2, \ldots\}$?